# Converting numeric(17,9) into a datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

In a data warehouse, I am building I am receiving DateTime data from one of our sources in numeric(17,9) format. Is there a way in SQL Server to convert the numeric to a DateTime and whilst retaining the time information? For example, a date such as 20210928.110424000 should be converted to 2021-09-28 11:04:24:000. I am able to convert this to 2021-09-28 00:00:00.000 but as you can see I am missing the time information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small matter with `STUFF()`.  You only need to be concerned with the time portion... yyyymmdd will convert to a date.

**Example**

```
Declare @V numeric(17,9) = 20210928.110424000
Select try_convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff(stuff(@V,16,0,'.'),14,0,':'),12,0,':'),9,1,' '))
```

**Results**

```
2021-09-28 11:04:24.000
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 2):

**The most performant way to do this** is probably to use `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` with arithmetic, rather than using string manipulation.

```
SELECT
  DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    CAST(@date AS int) / 10000,
    CAST(@date AS int) / 100 % 100,
    CAST(@date AS int) % 100,
    CAST(@date * 100 AS int) % 100,
    CAST(@date % 0.01 * 10000 AS int),
    CAST(@date % 0.0001 * 1000000 AS int),
    CAST(@date % 0.000001 * 1000000000 AS int)
    )
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d97cd31074a2e0c8ac9de98734ad4b0c)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, using `substring` would be:

```
declare @date numeric(17,9) = 20210928.110424000

-- mask 2021-09-28 11:04:24.000 (121)
select 
  convert(datetime,
    substring(convert(varchar(20),@date),1,4) + '-' +
    substring(convert(varchar(20),@date),5,2) + '-' +
    substring(convert(varchar(20),@date),7,2) + ' ' +
    substring(convert(varchar(20),@date),10,2) + ':' +
    substring(convert(varchar(20),@date),12,2) + ':' +
    substring(convert(varchar(20),@date),14,2) + '.' +
    substring(convert(varchar(20),@date),16,3)
  ,121)
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1da45d187198e7432bdf7f81cfffe3f8)

Nevertheless, in traditional BI environments, the dates used to be linked to date/time dimensions (with surrogate keys numeric), rather than date/datetime. This strategy allows you to group the data from the dimension, where for a given surrogate key (*i.e. YYYYMMDD*) you have any other attributes associated (year, quarter, semester, month, week, ...).